# Connecting two columns in two different comboBoxes

Tags: java, mysql, combobox

I connected MySql database with Java app, I see data from two different columns (Items, Price) but I want to connect them somehow, for example, if choose in first combobox item "Desk" the other combobox should automatic find "Desk" price and display it in second combobox. Anyone have idea how to make that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a changelistener for the first box, then have it go into another sql query which will populate the second box.  Check out this guide, it'll explain to you how to do it

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html

Comment: Is that the only way to do that?

Comment: Not necessarily but you will need a listener of some sort to make this work because you are basing the result of the second box to the result of the first.  Therefore, you need some indication that the first box has been filled, thus the listener.  This would be the easiest solution in my opinion

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me !

Answer (score 0):

First, I think that you don't want to ComboBoxes being correlated in such a way.  There must be a better design for your gui.

Is your ComboBox from JFace?  There are JFace Data Bindings.  Normally, you use them to automatically update your model if someone changes values in the user interface.  If your model contains an id from your database, both comboboxes can have a binding to this id.